# Как создать массив, заполненный своими объектами numpy python

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

нужен одномерный массив numpy, заполненный моими объектами

Comment: np.append не подходит ?

Comment: @Ieksa Создать list ваших объектов, скормить его функции `np.array(list_of_objects, dtype=object)`.